# BizTalk - custom adapter accessing Sql Server and File

Tags: adapter, biztalk

To control the flow of large batches through our system, I would like to have a BizTalk adapter that picks up a file just like the File adapter, but conditionally to make sure the system is ready for it. The condition would be a check in the application db (Sql Server) to see how many large batches are already being processed at the time. I guess what I want is an adapter that is somewhat of a mix of the (WCF-)Sql and File adapters.

I am of course familiar with the regular File and (WCF-)Sql adapters, but I am not aware of an adapter that more or less combines the functionality of those two.

Is creating a custom adapter that does this feasible (or even the only way to get this functionality), or is there another adapter that could handle this scenario? Or would you even suggest an entirely different solution? Any ideas and insights would be appreciated!

BTW I don't think it matters for the solution, but this is BTS 2016 currently, with an upgrade to 2020 coming this year.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?  Or, what exactly does 'make sure the system is ready for it' mean?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than writing a custom adapter, how about just having the file adapter pick up the file, have a send port adapter that inserts into a database table, and then poll that table, picking up in batches via a stored procedure.

I've used this approach and it helps even out the volume of messages being processed.  Also useful in scenerios there is a need to rebatch, rather than trying to use a scatter / gather pattern.

Comment: Definitely a valid suggestion, and we have in fact looked at this exact solution! However, one of the problems is that a multitude of ~40MB files with 10,000 records each are being dropped, and after reading the first few, BizTalk slows down noticeably, and once it starts throttling it takes forever for it to recover, especially as long as there are still files to pick up. That's why I'm searching for a method that starts controlling the file intake at the very start, depending on how many of these batches are already being processed.

Comment: @Patrick  What criteria is it throttling on?  Do you have the capacity to create more host instances to divide the load so you are less likely to get throttling. e.g. do you have separate Receive, Processing, Send & Tracking Hosts?  In addition you could create some host for the bulk files so other processes aren't impacted.

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom pipeline for this. It sleeps if you have more documents than you can handle. The biztalk throttling settings will kick in when too many receive pipelines are open at once.

**I can't guarantee this is bullet proof during shutdowns though. I'm not sure if Biztalk will wait for sleeping pipelines to complete.**

I used a site wide mutex to control access to a pair<value,datetime>.
The pair describes the the number of items processed and the beginning of the current processing window. If there are too many requests during the window it sleeps until the next window opens. If it accepts work to process it increments the mutex and continues. When the next window opens it resets the value and the datetime.

In my case an in memory table with row locks on a SQL server proved to be a workable site wide mutex with six biztalk servers.

YMMV

Comment: When you say "sleep", do you mean an actual Thread.Sleep, or do you have another mechanism for that? it would indeed need  thorough testing to see whether any sleeping messages are lost on a server crash / rfestart.

Comment: Yes, actual sleep(). As I said in bold above I don't know that this is safe. I suspect a normal shutdown will wait until the service exits, and the service won't exit until it processes after the next iteration of the timing window. The only other way to do this would be to interpose a gatekeeper program between your input and the receive ports. I suspect that's a lot safer if you have to guarantee no lost messages.